# connecting to a data source phpstorm

Tags: jdbc, odbc, mysql-connector, phpstorm

I'm trying to connect PHPStorm to the database on the server of my website, hosted on a Linux box at BlueHost.

In order to do this, I clicked the Data Sources tab on the right side of the screen, the + icon, and then *DB Data Source* a Data Source Properties dialog popped up. I entered a name for the source, set *Data Source Level* to *Project*. Then downloaded the MySQL Connector/J-5.1.18 JDBC Driver Files. This filled the JDBC Driver Class with about 6-7 classes, including *com.mysql.jdbc.Driver*.

The problem I believe I'm having is at the Database URL. it's asking for a jdbc:// url, which I'm not familiar with. I used the example format jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database] and my username and password.

For host, I've tried *localhost*, and the name of the mysql server *box###.bluehost.com*. port 3306, and the name of the database was pretty straightforward.

I received this error when trying to test the connection...

```
Connection to Data Source failed
java.sql.SQLException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2332)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
in RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:27)
in LocalDataSource.getConnection(LocalDataSource.java:105)
```

The major difference between this question and other questions here is that this is not to connect to a wamp or mamp stack, but a remote database.

Comment: **1)** The Question is -- does your remote database allows remote connections? If it is on shared hosting (or the server where MySQL is running is not **fully** controlled by you) then extremely likely that remote connections are disabled (for security and performance purposes). **2)** As for the actual connection string -- just use one of the examples in that drop down box and just fill your details (as long as remote server will accept such connection).

Comment: That's a good question... It looks like they do, but I was forced to add my IP address (range) to the allowed IP addresses. Once I did that, everything else went smoothly. :] thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BlueHost required that I add my IP Address range to the allowed access hosts list. I am on a shared hosting account, so BlueHost seems to allow remote connections on shared hosting accounts.

I did this by clicking "Remote MySQL" next to PHPMyAdmin in the cPanel for my hosting account. The cPanel automatically detected my IP range and suggested I add it. Once I did, everything else fell into place.

Thanks to LazyOne for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Mamp and you are facing this problem, Just open the MAMP and uncheck 'allow local access only'.

Comment: I guess this works for MAMP pro only.. is there a setting somewhere on some file for this option?